# Kohana 3.1 Query Count & Pagination

Tags: pagination, kohana

I am getting my feet wet with Kohana but having trouble with pagination. i get the following error :

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class
>   'Pagination' not found

following the unoffical wiki I amended the bootstrap file to include this:

```
Kohana::modules(array( 'database' => MODPATH.'database', 'userguide' => MODPATH.'userguide', 'pagination' => MODPATH.'pagination', ))
```

but that didn't seem to help.

my second question is with regards to query count.... I am surprised there is no function like $query-count() unless i opt for ORM instead i find this solution a bit clunky given that a query count is a must for every pagination request:

```
$result['count'] = $pagination_query->select('COUNT("*") AS result_count')->execute()->get('result_count');
```

Any suggestions?

thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kohana 3.1 does not come with the pagination module...
it must be downloaded from

https://github.com/kohana/pagination

then go to the class/kohana edit line 199 from ->uri to ->uri()

that does it

as to the query count....still searching.

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a count_last_query() function in the Database class which provided the total results of the last query run as it would be without any limit or offset, but they pulled it from version 3.0.9.  You can find the documentation of it here:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Database#count_last_query

I've actually built upon the code from that function to make my own count query function if you want to use that.

```
protected static function _pagedQuery($query) {
  $sql = (string)$query;
  if (stripos($sql, 'LIMIT') !== FALSE) {
    // Remove LIMIT from the SQL
    $sql = preg_replace('/\sLIMIT\s+[^a-z]+/i', ' ', $sql);
  }
  if (stripos($sql, 'OFFSET') !== FALSE) {
    // Remove OFFSET from the SQL
    $sql = preg_replace('/\sOFFSET\s+\d+/i', '', $sql);
  }
  if (stripos($sql, 'ORDER BY') !== FALSE) {
    // Remove ORDER BY from the SQL
    $sql = preg_replace('/\sORDER BY\s+`\w+`(\.`\w+`)?(\s+DESC|\s+ASC)?/i', '', $sql);
  }

  $db = Database::instance();
  $result = $db->query(Database::SELECT, '
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ' . $db->quote_identifier('total_rows') . '
    FROM (' . $sql . ') AS ' . $db->quote_table('counted_results'),
    TRUE
  );
  return (int)$result->current()->total_rows;
}
```